# streaming audio with html interaction

Tags: html, audio-streaming

Ultimately I need to have something like [this](http://www.earbits.com/play#station/editor-s-picks-editors-eclectic-mix), a streaming audio but when a song changes it also changes the photo and text.

For playing a mp3 file I've looked at a couple of examples like:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/07/26/music-portfolio-template/

http://mediaelementjs.com/

Now also I found this class:

http://navarr.me/ytaudio/

that plays audio from youtube urls.

In reality I prefer from youtube so to avoid having to load all the mp3's on my own server..but the overall goal is like earbits to play the song and control the image and text that go along with the song.  I usually post code in my questions so Im not sure where to start on this, I'm not asking for code to be done for me, just need an idea as to how I can go about this.

Thanks

ps. hope this isn't wrong to post.. :S

Comment: Are you playing individual files, or a constant stream?  What are you serving the audio with?  What specifically is your question... how to get the metadata as it changes?  Or how to modify the elements on the page?

Comment: ideally it would be a constant stream, but everytime the song changes in that stream it needs to change background image and text.

Comment: Right, but what are you sending from the server?  Or have you not done that part yet?  If you haven't, is there a particular reason you would want to go with a constant stream rather than buffering individual files?

Comment: ideally it would be used as a "radio" stream not an individual file stream. even though its just mp3's streaming the extra functionality behind it is more like a radio.

Comment: Can you expound on why you say it would be ideal to have a continuous stream?  I ask because getting individual files to work is much simpler.  While you can get a full stream to work, individual files are a far more reliable option, and much easier to work with.  You would want to use a continuous stream if you had a source that wasn't just a bunch of files, or needed some synchronization between clients that couldn't easily be faked with files.

Comment: actually by the sound of it u have more knowledge in this matter so if u recommend it being individual then I go for it aswell.  I just thought it would be best(or the recommended) way to go.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21664/discussion-between-brad-and-andres)